# Is it possible to replace a relay on a ncm300 zone controller?

Tags: hvac, thermostat, furnace, zoned-heating

I have an ncm300 zone controller which controls the 3 zones for my furnace and heat pump. There seems to be an issue with a relay sticking which is causing a continuous call for heat even when thermostats are turned off.

Is it possible to just replace the problem relay?

Comment: Replacing parts is the usual way of fixing stuff.  Best practice is to find the exact problem part, instead of just replacing parts still you find the fix.

Answer (score 2):

The NCM300 has soldered-in relays that are not in sockets. While it may be feasible to replace a relay if you're an experienced electronics DIYer, that won't necessarily fix the problem.

This is an "intelligent" zone controller. That big chip in the middle of the board is a microcontroller that's running a computer program that indirectly orders the relays to open or close through additional buffering circuitry.

In other words, the 24 volt contact closure in your wall thermostat is not directly driving your relay coils, and you have no way to know for sure if your relays are physically sticking closed or if they are being electronically commanded to remain closed. (You could find out by using voltmeter probes on the coil terminals on the back of the board while a relay is "stuck". No voltage means physically stuck. Voltage means it's being commanded to remain closed. Mind the shock hazard.)

"Intelligent" zone controllers can be damaged by static electricity. For example, if you walk across a carpet, then touch the wall thermostat and a spark leaps from your finger, you can zap the zone controller through the thermostat wire. Unexpected behavior may ensue.

This is a 3-zone controller. If you are using only two zones for furnace and heat pump and you don't have a third thermostat hooked up, you can simply abandon the sticking zone and use the one that's currently idle. This will only be feasible if the stuck relay releases and remains off when powered down, then powered up again.